# How can I change fontSize whenever I click on a text?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to change the **fontSize** by clicking on *DecreaseFont*, *IncreaseFont* texts.

It works. But whenever I click on *DecreaseFont* or *IncreaseFont* texts, whatever inside *TextInput* gets deleted, and the border of *TextInput* gets increased or decreased, so *FontSize* changes too. But I dont want the text inside *TextInput* to be deleted.

What should I do ?

Here is related code to this:

```
const MyInput = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {

  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(12);

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref,() => ({
    incFont: () => {
      setFontSize(fontSize => fontSize+2);
    },
    decFont: () => {
      setFontSize(fontSize => fontSize-2);
    }
  }))
  

  return(
    <TextInput
      value={props.value}
      onChange={(e) => props.setValue(e.target.value)}
      style={{ fontSize, borderColor: "red", borderWidth: 1 }}
    >      
    </TextInput>  )


})
```

Inside main function:

```
const inputRef = useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

 return(
<View>
 <MyInput ref={inputRef} value={value} setValue={setValue}/>
          <Text onPress={()=>inputRef.current.incFont()}>IncreaseFont</Text>
          <Text onPress={() => inputRef.current.decFont()}>DecreaseFont</Text>
</View>)
```

Comment: can you post a sandbox? i cannot reproduce your issue with a sample sandbox that i created

Comment: it works on sandbox, but not on my app... its made by someone else, https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-burnell-0h70g?file=/src/App.js but it doesnt work for my app, i dont know why

Comment: e.target.value doesnt work on mobile.. That may be the reason. So textInput doesnt have a value, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I solved it.
The code on my question works for *web*, but not for *mobile*.
`e.target.value` doesnt work for *mobile*. And on *changeText* event, e already gives the value, like `(e)=>e`

```
const MyInput = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {

  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(12);
  const [textInputValue, setTextInputValue] = React.useState('');


  React.useImperativeHandle(ref,() => ({
    incFont: () => {
      setFontSize(fontSize => fontSize+2);
    },
    decFont: () => {
      setFontSize(fontSize => fontSize-2);
    }
  }))
  
  return(
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={(text) => setTextInputValue(text)}
      value={textInputValue}
      style={{ fontSize, borderColor: "red", borderWidth: 1 }}
    >      
    </TextInput>  )
})
```

And i deleted *value,setValue* in main function,

```
<MyInput ref={inputRef}/>
```

it works perfectly